# Replace KafkaAttributesExtractor.GETTER.get when migrating to quarkus 3

Tags: quarkus, open-telemetry, opentracing

I am acutally migrating to quarkus 3 and the class io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.tracing.HeaderExtractAdapter which i was using to retrieve kafka headers has been removed.

I was using it like this :
HeaderExtractAdapter.GETTER.get(headers, headerName)

Do you know if i there are similar ways to do this with quarkus 3?

Thanks

I tried to look into the new package tracing but i couldnt find anything

Comment: This class was used by OpenTelemetry, which has evolved and broke compatibility. Now it's: `KafkaTraceTextMapGetter`. Except if you are in an OpenTelemetry context, I would rather avoid using this class which may be changed in the future (depending on OpenTelemetry evolution).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i refactor my code to use this and its working

Comment: @Clement that should probably be an actual answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class was used by OpenTelemetry, which has evolved and broke compatibility. Now it's: KafkaTraceTextMapGetter. Except if you are in an OpenTelemetry context, I would rather avoid using this class which may be changed in the future (depending on OpenTelemetry evolution).